# Point subdomain to root without using a subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following scenario:

- `blog.site.com` points to `server1`
- `site.com` points to `server2`.

I want `blog.site.com` to become `site.com/blog`. So I thought I'll point `blog.site.com` to `server2` and put in a subfolder `blog` where I can place an .htaccess file doing the 301 redirect. However by creating a blog subdirectory it overrides the `/blog/title-goes-here` with a blank directory.

My problem is `server1` is being decommissioned and so it won't be available to be used for the 301 redirect.

Is there a way I can point `blog.site.com` to `server2`to become `site.com/blog/title-goes-here` without using a `blog` subdirectory? Or using a `blog` subdirectory but not interfering with the url?

**Please note**. This is a wordpress website which the posts from serve1 have been imported. It's important to keep the blog as a part of the site.com website.

Comment: `it overrides the /blog/title-goes-here with a blank directory.` What?  I don't understand this. If you place the website in this directory, and you've ensured that 1.) You've modified the `home` and `site_url` values in the database, 2.) You've got a default wordpress index.php page, 3.) you've reset your permalinks and 4.) the standard code for the .htaccess has been modified to include `/blog/index.php` as opposed to just `index.php` then this should be a non issue.

Comment: `My problem is server1 is being decommissioned and so it won't be available to be used for the 301 redirect.` Well. You can point `blog.site.com` to `server2` and create a dedicated `VirtualHost` that respond to `blog.site.com` to handle 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you don't need a redirect - you need rewrite rules.

Have your DNS entries for blog.site.com and site.com point to server2.  Then in the `.htaccess` on server2 add the corresponding rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.site\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /blog/$1 [L]
```

Now whether you access `site.com` or `blog.site.com`, you'll end up accessing the same server.  The rewrite rule will then ensure that requests of type `blog.site.com/something` actually call `site.com/blog/something`.

Note that I haven't tested this though.

Comment: And the actual .htaccess file can be placed in the route? Not in a subdirectory? I've assumed that blog.site.com will be directed to the blog subdirectory?

Comment: You'll need to place `.htaccess` in the root.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. This didn't actually work. The redirect worked but because the subdomain is mapped to the subdirectory it was being overwritten by a blank directory. I ended up duplicating the root files in the blog subdirectory. I'll maybe see if I can use symlinks instead.

Comment: @iamjonesy You really have to explain yourself.  What do you mean by "overwritten by a blank directory"??  Someone already asked you this in the comment to your question, but you didn't respond.